# WhY I can not send debug or appstore build?

Tags: codenameone

I am having trouble sending  ios debug or appstore build.

According to the log my build size is 86kb. The log is not indicating something usefull as far as I can understand. Where else can I look for infomration?

The log is below:

```
jar:
clean-override:
build-for-ios-device:
Prompting for password
Building for username: christoforos@e-logism.gr
Checking provisioning profile for type iphone
Your build size is: 82kb
Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
Sending build to account: christoforos@e-logism.gr
Response message from server is: null
Server provided no further details
java.io.IOException: An upload error occured - check that you have enough build credits on the server
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:424)
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:445)
    at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:505)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor200.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
/home/User/NetBeansProjects/eiep/build.xml:96: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: java.io.IOException: An upload error occured - check that you have enough build credits on the server. Did you confirm if you have enough build credits?

Comment: I am sorry but I dont know what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran out of build credits. This happens when you send a lot of iOS builds which take up more build credits.

> With the free version you are limited to 100 build credits per month. Notice you can increase the following limits by referring your friends or if you were referred by a friend. See this [article for details](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/increase-your-build-quotas.html).
>
> 1 credit == 1 build
>
> Except for iOS where 8 credits == 1 build to offset the higher costs of Mac servers.

See: https://help.codenameone.com/en-us/article/is-codename-one-free-slkwhu/